# Cypress + Cucumber - Cypress automatically reloads page for each It in Describe

Tags: typescript, automation, cucumber, cypress, xpath-2.0

Hi I have strange problem. There is dialog window for which I've added data-cy attribute.
I have scenarios in cucumber like:

```
Scenario: Users open dialog window
  When user click open dialog button
```

For which I have corresponding cypress code:

```
it('user click open dialog button', () => {
    cy.get(element).click();
  })
```

To this moment everything is ok. However in the next scenarios (separate cypress tests described as **it**) I do several actions on this dialog window. Like adding text, some assertions etc. However when separate scenario is run the dialog window is immediately closed. If I put those actions in the same scenario (same cypress tests described as **it** then it works fine. However if I only try to separate those actions, window close and I have no clue why. Does cypress force close dialogs, popups etc. when new scenario begins? For sure in my code there is no action to close it I triple checked it. It just automatically closes whenever any new scenario starts. Is this some kind of cypress feature? I can't find any info about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I've found that for every it in describe cypress I don't know why reloads page automatically. I don't know why or how to turn it off. Its not the code nor the app - when I'm clicking manually there is no reloads by it self.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found solution. It comes to cucumber - at the test start I used cucumbers Given: User goes to URL ... but given is executed before **evry step** so it reload page and dialog window was gone. Switched given to regular scenario so it is performed only once. And now it works. Maybe some one will find it useful in the future :)

Cheers